# NHibernate Paging in Oracle - Using rownum

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, paging

I'm trying to do paging in NHibernate on Oracle DB. However, SetFirstResult & SetMaxResults do not work, even in NHibernate 3.3 (its unpredictable and often returns zero results).

I'm now trying to use "rownum" in the query to do the same. I tried this:

```
  finalCriteria
  .Add(Restrictions.Between(Projections.SqlProjection("rownum", new string[] { "RowNumber" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int64 }), rowIndex, rowIndex + pageSize));
```

However it does not work (ORA-00936: expression not found)

Any suggestions?

Here is one of the ways i used, in vain, SetFirst & SetMax

```
finalCriteria.SetFirstResults(pageIndex* pageSize).SetMaxResults(pageSize)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have been using Oracle with NHibernate for a few years now and never had a problem with paging except in a couple of extreme scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it doesn't work for you, but we use SetFirstResult and SetMaxResult on Oracle 11 with success. This is our code, very simular to yours:

```
criteria.SetFirstResult(pageSize * Offset);
criteria.SetMaxResults(pageSize);
```

I never noticed any problems. Did you check the sql statement hibernate creates?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Oracle with NHibernate for a few years now and never had a problem with paging except in a couple of extreme scenarios.  The SetFirstResult and SetMaxResults works.  You can use NHibernate Profiler http://www.nhprof.org and see the sql that is actually created.  This might help you out